# Gradle: How to customize Android Manifest permissions?

Tags: android, gradle

For my build system, I need to build several app variants, each requesting a different set of permissions. How can this be done with Gradle, without invoking a separate script?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I just managed to do this by having different flavors in my gradle file:

```
    free {
        packageName 'com.sample.free'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "HAS_AD", "true"
    }

    paid {
        packageName 'com.sample.paid'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "HAS_AD", "false"
    }
```

and then I created a new folder under src called "free" and under that a folder called "res"

```
src/
 + free/
 |   + res/
 + src/
```

and in that folder create a new file "AndroidManifest.xml" with the following code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.sample" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

According to [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) on Android Tools Project Site:

> Similar to Build Types, Product Flavors also contribute code and
>   resources through their own sourceSets.

and

> The following rules are used when dealing with all the sourcesets used
>   to build a single APK:
>
> - All source code (src/*/java) are used together as multiple folders    generating a single output.
> - *Manifests are all merged together into a single manifest. This allows Product Flavors to have different components and/or
>     permissions, similarly to Build Types.*
> - All resources (Android res and assets) are used using overlay priority    where the Build Type overrides the Product Flavor, which
>     overrides    the main sourceSet.
> - Each Build Variant generates its own R class (or    other generated source code) from the resources. Nothing is shared    between
>     variants.

meaning that you can create a folder with each flavor name under src and put your custom files in them. If said file is an AndroidManifest gradle will merge it with the manifest in the main.