# Adding Android AppWidget just for one Product Flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-appwidget, android-productflavors

I have two `gradle` `product flavors`: for prod and for stage server.

```
productFlavors {
        stage {
            // stage specific stuff
        }
        production {
            // production only
        }
    }
```

Also I have an AppWidget must be able only for stage now. I think I should hide my `AppWidgetProvider` in manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".appwidget.AppWidgetProvider"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
       android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
       android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```

But how can I do it just for prod product flavor? Or is there another way here?

Comment: Are you looking for something that is related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408480/gradle-how-to-customize-android-manifest-permissions

Comment: no, I'm not. put the working instructions and the bounty is yours) do not forget that I need to hide element inside <application> tag

Comment: I think I can provide you a small example which loads two separate manifests, wouldn't this be a more ideal solution?

Comment: Nvm I have a better solution than that, I will provide below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we will have our example packages is as follows for your production and staging builds within the gradle product flavors.

```
productFlavors {
        production {
            packageName "x(path).x(path).gradleexample"
        }

        staging {
            packageName "x(path).x(path).gradleexample.staging"
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of your folder structure some of which may or may not apply to your project but should give you a run down of what is needed.

```
├── main
│   ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│   ├── ic_launcher-web.png
│   ├── java
│   │   └── x(path)
│   │       └── x(path)
│   │           └── gradlebuildexample
│   │               └── MainActivity.java
│   └── res
│       ├── drawable-hdpi
│       │   └── ic_launcher.png
│       ├── drawable-mdpi
│       │   └── ic_launcher.png
│       ├── drawable-xhdpi
│       │   └── ic_launcher.png
│       ├── drawable-xxhdpi
│       │   └── ic_launcher.png
│       ├── layout
│       │   └── activity_main.xml
│       ├── menu
│       │   └── main.xml
│       ├── values
│       │   ├── dimens.xml
│       │   ├── strings.xml
│       │   └── styles.xml
│       ├── values-v11
│       │   └── styles.xml
│       └── values-v14
│           └── styles.xml
├── production
│   └── java
│       └── x(path)
│           └── x(path)
│               └── gradlebuildexample
│                   └── Constants.java
└── staging
    ├── java
    │   └── x(path)
    │       └── x(path)
    │           └── gradlebuildexample
    │               └── Constants.java
    └── res
        ├── drawable-hdpi
        │   └── ic_launcher.png
        ├── drawable-mdpi
        │   └── ic_launcher.png
        ├── drawable-xhdpi
        │   └── ic_launcher.png
        ├── drawable-xxhdpi
        │   └── ic_launcher.png
        └── values
            └── string.xml
```

Now to be clear your string result set xml in the production and staging, among the values -> string.xml, will have to contain the following value appropriate for the manifest which will be described below.

So something like as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="receiver">false</string>
</resources>
```

With my current understanding of your manifest it would look something like this

```
<receiver
    android:name=".appwidget.AppWidgetProvider"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:enabled="@string/receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
       android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
       android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```

So this would work, but if you saw from my third comment, a much better and simpler solution would be to have a different manifest for each build phase, because you may want more changes than just one. So below I will provide that work around as well which you can extrapolate on what I have provided.

Using [source set](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSet.html) in gradle you can specify a different build path for each manifest as follows

```
sourceSets {

        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }

        debug {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/debug/res']
        }

        release {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/release/AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/release/res']
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on the other answer by @kev2316, here's a simpler way to accomplish that:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
    android:resource="@xml"
    android:enabled="@bool/widget_enabled"/>
```

And in your `build.gradle`:

```
productFlavors {
    production {
        resValue "bool", "widget_enabled", "true"
    }
    staging {
        resValue "bool", "widget_enabled", "false"
    }
}
```

Comment: nice addition, I forgot you could do that.

Comment: Thank you all, I'll try suggested three ways and then close the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tried all approaches and they all work:)
I award @kev2316 with the bounty because all the ways base on his ideas.

And for future readers I want to leave some comments how I solve the problem in my project.

1. let the `AndroidManifest.xml` in `app/src/main` stay immutable
2. create `AndroidManifest.xml` in `app/src/stage` with this content.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>      package="my.package" >
> <application>
> <!-- Declarations for the widget -->
>     <receiver
>         android:name=".appwidget.AppWidgetProvider"
>         android:label="@string/app_name">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
>         </intent-filter>
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
>             android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info" />
>     </receiver>
>     <service
>         android:name=".appwidget.AppWidgetRefreshService"
>         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"
>         android:exported="false" />
> </application>
> </manifest>
> ```

3. Profit! The result `AndroidManifest.xml` merges by `gradle` automatically. I have a custom `Application` class for the project, but it works perfect.

This approach is more common than turning off `receiver` with `enabled` option and allow to configure `receiver` and `service` as usual. Also I have to create just one additional file, so it's quite simple.