# How to refer to a String var defined in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio

I hope to display different app name  based free and pro version.

I define `buildConfigField "String", "AppName", "\"Message Cleanup\""` in build.gradle, but I don't know how to apply to android:label in AndroidManifest.xml.

Could you help me ? Thanks!

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.dodata.messagecleanup" >



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/clenupmessage"
        android:label="AppName"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity android:name="ui.CleanupDelete"
            android:label="AppName">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>       


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.dodata.messagecleanup"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.07"
        archivesBaseName = "MessageCleanup-V" + versionName
    }


    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "info.dodata.messagecleanup"
            buildConfigField "String", "AppName", "\"Message Cleanup\""
        }


        pro {
            applicationId "info.dodata.messagecleanup.pro"
            buildConfigField "String", "AppName", "\"Message Cleanup Pro\""
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

**To kcoppock**

The manifestPlaceholders can do that.

```
productFlavors {

wandoujia {
manifestPlaceholders = [UMENG_CHANNEL_VALUE: "wandoujia"]
}

baidu {
manifestPlaceholders = [UMENG_CHANNEL_VALUE: "New"]
}

c360 {
manifestPlaceholders = [UMENG_CHANNEL_VALUE: "c360"]
}

uc {
manifestPlaceholders = [UMENG_CHANNEL_VALUE: "uc"]
}

}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml, I can use it as the following code

```
 <meta-data
android:name="UMENG_CHANNEL"
android:value="${UMENG_CHANNEL_VALUE}" />
```

Comment: you can't. `buildConfigField` are fields for the `BuildConfig` class (!)

Comment: Thanks! How can I display different app name based free and pro version ?

Comment: you can create different AndroidManifest.xml for your flavours. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408480/gradle-how-to-customize-android-manifest-permissions

Comment: Thanks! Is there other simpe way ?

Comment: Thanks!  To njzk2,  I updated my question, I google some document, it seems that I can use String var defined in build.gradle in xml  via manifestPlaceholders,is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the standard project structure (e.g. you have something like `src/main/res/values/strings.xml`), create additional directories for each flavor:

```
src/free/res/values/strings.xml
src/pro/res/values/strings.xml
```

And define the same string key (e.g. `app_name`) in both of those files, with the correct value for each variant. So you'd have something like:

**src/free/res/values/strings.xml**

```
<string name="app_name">Message Cleanup</string>
```

**src/pro/res/values/strings.xml**

```
<string name="app_name">Message Cleanup Pro</string>
```

The resource merger will merge in these strings based on which variant is being built. Now you can just refer to the `app_name` string in code, and know that it'll render correctly based on the currently built flavor.

Comment: Thanks! Would you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783459/what-will-toast-display-when-i-use-productflavors-in-build-gradle

Comment: Thanks! but In android studio, I can't test free version or pro version by clicking "Run" button in Android Studio, I have to generate different version signed APK file and install it to my mobile phone to test.

Comment: @HelloCW you can use the Build Variants panel on the left hand side of Android Studio to switch between flavors.

Comment: Thanks! it works.  Are you sure that I can't use buildConfigField in my code?  you know I can use BuildConfig.FLAVOR in my java code.

Comment: Sure, from in code you can do that, but you can't use it from XML (i.e. your manifest in this case).

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question, I google some documents, it seems that I can use String var defined in build.gradle in xml  via manifestPlaceholders,is it correct?

Comment: Ah yes, that is true, although I still wouldn't recommend it for user facing strings. If it's just build configuration stuff like API keys or whatever, that's a good solution.