# What will Toast display when I use productFlavors in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created following project in `Android Studio`, and clicked on "**Run**" button in `Android Studio` to run the `app`.

In my mind, `Android Studio` will run the `app` with debug model, but what will `Toast` display? will it display the one of following options?

> A: com.example.my.myapplication FLAVOR free
>
> B: com.example.my.myapplication FLAVOR pro
>
> C: info.dodata.messagecleanup FLAVOR free
>
> D: info.dodata.messagecleanup FLAVOR pro

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String versionName = getPackageName()+" FLAVOR "+BuildConfig.FLAVOR;

        if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "pro") {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), versionName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), versionName , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }  
}
```

***build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.my.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }


    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "info.dodata.messagecleanup"
        }

        pro {
            applicationId "info.dodata.messagecleanup.pro"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.my.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```